# gdal_translate closes without any error when translating a big tif to map

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, powershell

I run gdal_translate from powershell for file:

```
Size is 32571, 35947
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Asia_North_Lambert_Conformal_Conic",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",15],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",65],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",30],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",95],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (166653.014255152433179,5265477.987697909586132)
Pixel Size = (90.000000000000000,-90.000000000000000)
Metadata:
   AREA_OR_POINT=Area
   Image Structure Metadata:
   INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
   Upper Left  (  166653.014, 5265477.988) (100d58'10.03"E, 78d28'26.65"N)
   Lower Left  (  166653.014, 2030247.988) ( 97d32'39.43"E, 50d 4' 8.85"N)
   Upper Right ( 3098043.014, 5265477.988) (173d27'56.39"E, 66d15'12.80"N)
   Lower Right ( 3098043.014, 2030247.988) (138d15'18.78"E, 42d12'48.85"N)
   Center      ( 1632348.014, 3647862.988) (128d12'55.62"E, 62d29'33.13"N)
Band 1 Block=32571x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-9999
Input file size is 32571, 35947
```

With a command:

```
gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of PCRaster -b 1 -mo VS_SCALAR ${INPATH}\${DEMFILE} ${OUT}\dem.map
```

gdalinfo is run properly, gdal is working from powershell

What's the reason of this problem and how can I see which is the error?

Comment: Does conversion into GeoTIFF succeed `-of GTiff -ot Float32 -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate`? Add `--debug on` into your command and you may get more information.

Comment: Yes! Conversion to Tif for the same file is succeeding well. So the problem is in PCRaster format? But parameters are the same I used in Python

Comment: --debug on is not detected by progrem as known key

Comment: Is it also the same with `gdalinfo --debug on`? I think that it is possible to compile GDAL without debug support, perhaps you have such version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an empty test image based on your gdalinfo with a gdal_create command

```
gdal_create -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -co compress=deflate -ot Int16 -outsize 32571 35947 -a_ullr 166653.014 5265477.988 3098043.014 2030247.988 pcraster.tif

gdalinfo:
Files: pcraster.tif
Size is 32571, 35947
Origin = (166653.013999999995576,5265477.987999999895692)
Pixel Size = (90.000000000000000,-90.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  166653.014, 5265477.988)
Lower Left  (  166653.014, 2030247.988)
Upper Right ( 3098043.014, 5265477.988)
Lower Right ( 3098043.014, 2030247.988)
Center      ( 1632348.014, 3647862.988)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Then I tried the conversion with your command

```
gdal_translate -ot Float32 -of PCRaster -b 1 -mo VS_SCALAR pcraster.tif pcraster.map --debug on
```

Gdal_translate runs normally and gdalinfo about the result is

```
Driver: PCRaster/PCRaster Raster File
Files: pcraster.map
       pcraster.map.aux.xml
Size is 32571, 35947
Origin = (166653.013999999995576,5265477.987999999895692)
Pixel Size = (90.000000000000000,-90.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  PCRASTER_VALUESCALE=VS_SCALAR
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  166653.014, 5265477.988)
Lower Left  (  166653.014, 2030247.988)
Upper Right ( 3098043.014, 5265477.988)
Lower Right ( 3098043.014, 2030247.988)
Center      ( 1632348.014, 3647862.988)
Band 1 Block=32571x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=0.000 Max=0.000
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
```

I can't say what is the reason for your problem, but the conversion that you try to do seems to be possible.
I used GDAL 3.7.0dev for testing.

Comment: I have GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19
I was installed with OsGeo (QGIS)

Comment: Upgrade and try again. The latest release is 3.6.2.

Comment: Upgrade with conda? I don't see any other possibility for GDAL

Comment: If you have used OSGeo installer before, use the same. If you also using some very old QGIS version, I recommend upgrading it by the same.

Comment: I upgraded with conda and it worked within conda enviromment. Thanks to all